# Django - ImportError: Could not import 'drf_yasg.generators.OpenAPISchemaGenerator' for API setting

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-swagger

I'm trying to add https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg this library to our django application and getting the below error.

```
permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/drf_yasg/views.py", line 67, in get_schema_view
    _generator_class = generator_class or swagger_settings.DEFAULT_GENERATOR_CLASS
  File "env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/drf_yasg/app_settings.py", line 122, in __getattr__
    val = perform_import(val, attr)
  File "env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/settings.py", line 166, in perform_import
    return import_from_string(val, setting_name)
  File "env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/settings.py", line 180, in import_from_string
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Could not import 'drf_yasg.generators.OpenAPISchemaGenerator' for API setting 'DEFAULT_GENERATOR_CLASS'. ImportError: cannot import name 'URLPattern' from 'rest_framework.compat' (env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/compat.py).
```

after some research I found some people suggested installing this package to solve the issue

```
pip3 install packaging
```

But this is not making any difference. Any other good api documentation library available for django rest api?

Answer (score 14):

### UPDATE

The issue has been fixed in [**`drf-yasg==1.20.0`**--(Release notes)](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/releases/tag/1.20.0) so that you can upgrade to the latest version by

```
pip install drf-yasg -U
```

---

#### Original answer

There is an open issue in [drf-yasg-(#641)](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/641) to fix this issue. Unfortunately, the project is no longer maintained given that there has been no activity since *Feb 2020* (Ref [this](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/641#issuecomment-704238762)).

But, [@JoelLefkowitz](https://github.com/JoelLefkowitz) created a fork of the project and it is available in named [**drf-yasg2**](https://github.com/JoelLefkowitz/drf-yasg) which has been fixed the OP's issue.

What you need to do is, migrate from `drf-yasg` to [**`drf-yasg2`**--(ReadTheDoc)](https://drf-yasg2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

#### Installation

```
pip install drf-yasg2
```

and add it to the **`INSTALLED_APPS`** section

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
      ...
      'drf_yasg2',
      ...
   ]
```

Comment: I have used the ones given in https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/ without additional `pip` using `openapi` shchemas. But newly added apis are not displayed in openapi url or swagger ui only the old ones. any extra step we need after adding new apis?

Comment: I am not sure what you have got. It is better to ask a new question regarding the new issue.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC I think that you can upgrade `drf-yasg==1.20.0`, since this issue was fixed in a new release (https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/641)

Comment: @machin I have updated the answer with the reference. Thanks for the update!!!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like DRF does not have `rest_framework.compat.URLPattern` starting from version `3.12`, and drf-yasg have not caught up on this yet. Make sure that your DRF version is less than 3.12. For example: `pip install djangorestframework==3.11.2`

Comment: But we have developed some of the API's and I think downgrading is not a good solution at this stage.

Comment: If you check https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg, it says that it supports only following versions of DRF - 3.8, 3.9, 3.10, 3.11. If your code requires other version of DRF, than I am afraid drf-yasg will not work for you. Try downgrading, most likely it won't cause your code to break.

Comment: Erm... you generally don't downgrade a core application library for a documentation generator.

Comment: Typically yes, unless you really want that generator, and downgrade is minor one. This craft all about trade-offs :). Another option might be fixing drf-yasg and submitting PR, using in the app your patched version until the fix is merged/released.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me

```
pip install drf-yasg -U
```

Answer (score 0):

**It could surely help you guys** write this in **settings.py** file:

SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
"DEFAULT_GENERATOR_CLASS": "rest_framework.schemas.generators.BaseSchemaGenerator",
}